# Copy Headers section not visible in Build Phases of Xcode

Tags: ios, macos, xcode4.5

I've read other posts relating to this but they don't have the same issue as I'm having.

I'm transitioning from one project that supports the OS X platform to a new project that supports iOS.

I do have one project open with the Copy Headers sub-heading visible. Its supported platform is OS X, and is what I'm transitioning from.

[image: Build Phases with Copy Headers]

My new iOS project that I wish to use the Copy Headers build phase looks like:

[image: Build Phases without Copy Headers]

Can anyone tell me why these projects have different Build Phase sub-headings? The only difference I can see under Build Settings is that the former example doesn't have a **Prefix Header** while the latter has **Copy Files**.

Comment: Copy headers is unnecessary because static libraries are all that are supported on iOS.  With DyLibs, you could export the headers as public (they actually get their own directory along with the framework executable), hence the need for those sub-levels of the "Copy Headers" phase.  In addition, the copy files phase on iOS is also present on OS X, it's just not a standard part of the project (click the + in the lower right to add it to your build phases).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, @CodaFi. Your response yielded the answer to my question. Clicking the + "Add Build Setting" at the bottom of the window gives me the option of adding Copy Headers to my new project. For the sake of completeness and leaving no stone unturned if I run into problems later, I will feel safer including this option though you say it doesn't provide any benefit because iOS only supports static libraries and not dynamic libraries.

Great!